# Ubuntu Unity 16.10 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified'

Tags: unity, scripts, sudo, 16.10

I made a script to set/unset the proxy setting for when I switch between work and home. The script works perfectly and now I wanna run it every time automatically when I login so I put it in my .profile (like : source ~/bin/proxyscript.sh).

This works when I was using Ubuntu Gnome and during login I get a terminal and it asked for the sudo password. Since version 16.10 I installed a clean version of Ubuntu Unity and now I get the error message "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" when I login.

In the script I do something like :

```
sudo service cntlm stop
sudo sed ..... /etc/cntlm.conf
sudo service. cntlm start
```

I already looked at the /etc/sudoers file and added the following without a good result:

```
Defaults        !/usr/bin/sed !requiretty
Defaults        !/usr/sbin/service !requiretty

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
jeroen  ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/sed, /usr/sbin/service
```

I don't know what I now can try to fix this problem. Anyone any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: you should not use sudo in a script

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `sudo` in a script. You can use policykit instead of `sudo` in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkexec env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority service cntlm stop & sed whatever is missing here
pkexec env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority service cntlm start
```

or, better yet . . . just do the sed command first and then restart the service so that you only need to enter a password twice

```
#!/bin/bash
pkexec env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority sed 'some sed stuff' 
pkexec env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority service cntlm restart
```

Also, if you still have problems, I would suggest running the script from "startup applications" instead of from your `.profile` file. You can search for "startup applications in your dash"

Comment: I'm going to replace sudo with what you say. But do I than also need to keep my changes to the /etc/sudoers file ?

Comment: @JdKock No, I would recommend changing the sudoers file back to normal. It's probably not good security to have stuff like sed set to execute without permission like that. As for the popup, this is a normal message.

Comment: Oke I changed the sudoers file back to normal and take the popup as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my script and replaced the `sudo` for :

`pkexec env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority sed 'some sed stuff'`

This worked, thanks mchild !

Now I get a popup to enter my password. With the message :
`Authentication is needed to run '/usr/bin/env' as the super user`

But is it also possible without to enter a password ?